# Error on deploying a SharePoint 2010 site template

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010

I have a web application in which I have few document libraries, lists, picture libraries, workflows and few webparts. The webparts are created using visual studio with the feature site scoped. WorkFlows are created using SPD. Everyting working fine in my local SharePoint server. I want to copy my web application to a different server. For this I saved the site template Site `Actions-> Save Site as template`, saved the wsp to my desktop. Then I took the wsp to the other server machine where i created a **webapplication**.

Then using PowerShell command added the solution using Add-SPSolution command. When trying to install using Install-SPSolution command **I got an error:**

> This solution contains no resources scoped for a web application and cannot be deployed to a particular web application

I tried to change the scope of webpart feature to Web/WebApplication but encountered error when tried to deployed using visual studio.

How can I deploy the wsp in a different SharePoint Server machine?

Answer (score 0):

When you save the site as a template, you'll only save the site, not your web application. Create the web application first (maybe without a site template), and roll out your site from your WSP afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using powershell to deploy the solutions, please remember to include the flag -GACDeployment.